# Where can I find the SONOS Cloud Queue server sample the docs are talking about?

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to get started with SONOS programmed radio feature, but I can't seem to find their Cloud Queue server sample referenced in the docs. Namely, the docs (this [link](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/account-matching/)) says the following:

> A cloud queue to serve the list of tracks to Sonos players. See our cloud queue sample server for a sample implementation and Play audio for details about cloud queues.

with [cloud queue sample server](https://developer.sonos.com/tools/sample-servers/cloud-queue-server-sample/) receiving 403 File Not Found

I noticed the same thing happens in the case of another sample code of theirs, also referenced in the docs (this [link](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/playback-sessions/)) here:

> For example, we handle this on our Android cloud queue sample app by moving music playback to the local device so that it continues playing on the local device and stops playing on Sonos.

with [Android cloud queue sample app](https://developer.sonos.com/tools/sample-apps/android-cloud-queue-sample-app/) receiving same HTTP error.

How can I access this needed samples?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Interesting, the only sample they have now is their SMAPI server at https://developer.sonos.com/tools/

Comment: they're back up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just received this email from developer-feedback@sonos.com

> Hello,
>
> You should find the links to these samples restored. Let us know if
> you encounter further issues. Disclaimer: we are not actively
> maintaining these samples and they are provided as-is.
>
> Best, Sonos Sound Platform Team

I verified the links and they're working